# Difference between array_map, array_walk and array_filter

Tags: php, arrays, callback

What exactly is the difference between `array_map`, `array_walk` and `array_filter`. What I could see from documentation is that you could pass a callback function to perform an action on the supplied array. But I don't seem to find any particular difference between them.

Do they perform the same thing?
Can they be used interchangeably?

I would appreciate your help with illustrative example if they are different at all.

Comment: This is a cool trick for named array processing via array_reduce().  Worth a read if you are investigating array_map, array_walk, and array_filter.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563119/array-map-callback-access-to-associative-array-key-and-value/15303635#15303635

Answer (score 648, accepted):

- Changing Values:

  - [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) cannot change the values inside input array(s) while [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk) can; in particular, [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) never changes its arguments.
- Array Keys Access:
- [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) cannot operate with the array keys, [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk) can.
- Return Value:
- [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) returns a new array, [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk) only returns `true`. Hence, if you don't want to create an array as a result of traversing one array, you should use [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk).
- Iterating Multiple Arrays:
- [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) also can receive an arbitrary number of arrays and it can iterate over them in parallel, while [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk) operates only on one.
- Passing Arbitrary Data to Callback:
- [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk) can receive an extra arbitrary parameter to pass to the callback. This mostly irrelevant since PHP 5.3 (when [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) were introduced).
- Length of Returned Array:
- The resulting array of `array_map` has the same length as that of the largest input array; `array_walk` does not return an array but at the same time it cannot alter the number of elements of original array; [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) picks only a subset of the elements of the array according to a filtering function. It does preserve the keys.

Example:

```
<pre>
<?php

$origarray1 = array(2.4, 2.6, 3.5);
$origarray2 = array(2.4, 2.6, 3.5);

print_r(array_map('floor', $origarray1)); // $origarray1 stays the same

// changes $origarray2
array_walk($origarray2, function (&$v, $k) { $v = floor($v); }); 
print_r($origarray2);

// this is a more proper use of array_walk
array_walk($origarray1, function ($v, $k) { echo "$k => $v", "\n"; });

// array_map accepts several arrays
print_r(
    array_map(function ($a, $b) { return $a * $b; }, $origarray1, $origarray2)
);

// select only elements that are > 2.5
print_r(
    array_filter($origarray1, function ($a) { return $a > 2.5; })
);

?>
</pre>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
0 => 2.4
1 => 2.6
2 => 3.5
Array
(
    [0] => 4.8
    [1] => 5.2
    [2] => 10.5
)
Array
(
    [1] => 2.6
    [2] => 3.5
)
```

Comment: The PHP manual says: "array_walk(): Only the values of the array may potentially be changed;"

Comment: "array_map cannot operate with the array keys" this is not true:
```array_map(callback($key, $value), array_keys($array), $array)```

Comment: It's still not accessing the keys of any array, it's acessing the values you put in an array that you created from the keys. It's a workaround, it doesn't negate the statement.

Comment: while array_map doesn't implicitly change values, by assigning the result to the same array it basically changes it, and 'paradoxically' array_walk which operates on the same array itself won't change its values-directly, unless passed value by reference (array walk might remove indexes/elements as array_filter indirectly via anonymous function use clause passing the original array but it's a workaround). To conclude thus, changing values, nor if a value is returned or passed by reference is of less difference effectively, but array walk works with indexes and array map with multiple arrays

Comment: furthermore looks like that no matter that array walk takes the first, array parameter as a reference, when one wants to change it he has to pass also the callback item value as a reference

Answer (score 98):

The idea of [mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) an function to array of data comes from functional programming. You shouldn't think about `array_map` as a `foreach` loop that calls a function on each element of the array (even though that's how it's implemented). It should be thought of as applying the function to each element in the array independently.

In theory such things as function mapping can be done in parallel since the function being applied to the data should ONLY affect the data and NOT the global state. This is because an `array_map` could choose any order in which to apply the function to the items in (even though in PHP it doesn't).

`array_walk` on the other hand it the exact opposite approach to handling arrays of data. Instead of handling each item separately, it uses a state (`&$userdata`) and can edit the item in place (much like a foreach loop). Since each time an item has the `$funcname` applied to it, it could change the global state of the program and therefor requires a single *correct* way of processing the items.

Back in PHP land, `array_map` and `array_walk` are almost identical except `array_walk` gives you more control over the iteration of data and is normally used to "change" the data in-place vs returning a new "changed" array.

`array_filter` is really an application of `array_walk` (or `array_reduce`) and it more-or-less just provided for convenience.

Comment: +1 for your 2nd paragraph insight of "In theory such things as function mapping can be done in parallel since the function being applied to the data should ONLY effect the data and NOT the global state." For us parallel programmers, that's a useful thing to keep in mind.

Comment: Can you explain how `array_filter()` can be implemented using `array_walk()`?

Comment: @pfrenssen it is not possible to implement _filter_ with a _walk_; as mentioned in _"Length of Returned Array"_ from [https://stackoverflow.com/a/3432266/3088045](@Artefacto 's answer), the number of elements cannot be altered when using _walk_.

Answer (score 45):

From the documentation,

> bool array_walk ( array &$array , callback $funcname [, mixed $userdata ] ) <-return bool

[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) takes an array and a function `F` and modifies it by replacing every element x with `F(x)`.

> array array_map ( callback $callback ,
>   array $arr1 [, array $... ] )<-return array

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) does the exact same thing **except** that instead of modifying in-place it will return a new array with the transformed elements.

> array array_filter ( array $input [,
>   callback $callback ] )<-return array

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with function `F`, instead of transforming the elements, will remove any elements for which `F(x)` is not true

Comment: Couldn't figure out why my array values disappeared. Looking at documentation I assumed `array_walk` returned an array like `array_map` and figured the issue was in my function. Didn't realize until I saw this that the return type is boolean.

Answer (score 24):

The other answers demonstrate the difference between array_walk (in-place modification) and array_map (return modified copy) quite well. However, they don't really mention [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), which is an illuminating way to understand array_map and array_filter.

The array_reduce function takes an array, a two-argument function and an 'accumulator', like this:

```
array_reduce(array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
             'my_function',
             $accumulator)
```

The array's elements are combined with the accumulator one at a time, using the given function. The result of the above call is the same as doing this:

```
my_function(
  my_function(
    my_function(
      my_function(
        $accumulator,
        'a'),
      'b'),
    'c'),
  'd')
```

If you prefer to think in terms of loops, it's like doing the following (I've actually used this as a fallback when array_reduce wasn't available):

```
function array_reduce($array, $function, $accumulator) {
  foreach ($array as $element) {
    $accumulator = $function($accumulator, $element);
  }
  return $accumulator;
}
```

This looping version makes it clear why I've called the third argument an 'accumulator': we can use it to accumulate results through each iteration.

So what does this have to do with array_map and array_filter? It turns out that they're both a particular kind of array_reduce. We can implement them like this:

```
array_map($function, $array)    === array_reduce($array, $MAP,    array())
array_filter($array, $function) === array_reduce($array, $FILTER, array())
```

Ignore the fact that array_map and array_filter take their arguments in a different order; that's just another quirk of PHP. The important point is that the right-hand-side is identical except for the functions I've called $MAP and $FILTER. So, what do they look like?

```
$MAP = function($accumulator, $element) {
  $accumulator[] = $function($element);
  return $accumulator;
};

$FILTER = function($accumulator, $element) {
  if ($function($element)) $accumulator[] = $element;
  return $accumulator;
};
```

As you can see, both functions take in the $accumulator and return it again. There are two differences in these functions:

- $MAP will always append to $accumulator, but $FILTER will only do so if $function($element) is TRUE.
- $FILTER appends the original element, but $MAP appends $function($element).

Note that this is far from useless trivia; we can use it to make our algorithms more efficient!

We can often see code like these two examples:

```
// Transform the valid inputs
array_map('transform', array_filter($inputs, 'valid'))

// Get all numeric IDs
array_filter(array_map('get_id', $inputs), 'is_numeric')
```

Using array_map and array_filter instead of loops makes these examples look quite nice. However, it can be very inefficient if $inputs is large, since the first call (map or filter) will traverse $inputs and build an intermediate array. This intermediate array is passed straight into the second call, which will traverse the whole thing again, then the intermediate array will need to be garbage collected.

We can get rid of this intermediate array by exploiting the fact that array_map and array_filter are both examples of array_reduce. By combining them, we only have to traverse $inputs once in each example:

```
// Transform valid inputs
array_reduce($inputs,
             function($accumulator, $element) {
               if (valid($element)) $accumulator[] = transform($element);
               return $accumulator;
             },
             array())

// Get all numeric IDs
array_reduce($inputs,
             function($accumulator, $element) {
               $id = get_id($element);
               if (is_numeric($id)) $accumulator[] = $id;
               return $accumulator;
             },
             array())
```

NOTE: My implementations of array_map and array_filter above won't behave exactly like PHP's, since my array_map can only handle one array at a time and my array_filter won't use "empty" as its default $function. Also, neither will preserve keys.

It's not difficult to make them behave like PHP's, but I felt that these complications would make the core idea harder to spot.

Answer (score 1):

The following revision seeks to more clearly delineate PHP's array_filer(), array_map(), and array_walk(), all of which originate from functional programming:

array_filter() filters out data, producing as a result a new array holding only the desired items of the former array, as follows:

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "apples",2, "oranges",3, "plums");

$filtered = array_filter( $array, "ctype_alpha");
var_dump($filtered);
?>
```

live code [here](https://3v4l.org/9SdgU)

All numeric values are filtered out of $array, leaving $filtered with only types of fruit.

array_map() also creates a new array but unlike array_filter() the resulting  array contains *every* element of the input $filtered but with altered values, owing to applying a callback to each element, as follows:

```
<?php

$nu = array_map( "strtoupper", $filtered);
var_dump($nu);
?>
```

live code [here](https://3v4l.org/r8Cve)

The code in this case applies a callback using the built-in strtoupper() but a user-defined function is another viable option, too.  The callback applies to every item of $filtered and thereby engenders $nu whose elements contain uppercase values.

In the next snippet, array walk() traverses $nu and makes changes to each element vis a vis the reference operator '&'. The changes occur without creating an additional array. Every element's value changes in place into a more informative string specifying its key, category and value.

```
<?php

$f = function(&$item,$key,$prefix) {
    $item = "$key: $prefix: $item";
}; 
array_walk($nu, $f,"fruit");
var_dump($nu);    
?>
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/uNEVV)

Note: the callback function with respect to array_walk() takes two parameters which will automatically acquire an element's value and its key and in that order, too when invoked by array_walk(). (See more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)).

Comment: Note that the functions `$lambda` and `$callback` are just eta-expansions of existing functions, and are hence completely redundant. You can get the same result by passing (the name of) the underlying function: `$filtered = array_filter($array, 'ctype_alpha');` and `$nu = array_map('strtoupper', $filtered);`