# array_walk or array_map?

Tags: php, arrays, return-value

I'm currently using `array_map` to apply callbacks to elements of an array. But I want to be able to pass an argument to the callback function like `array_walk` does.
I suppose I could just use `array_walk`, but I need the return value to be an array like if you use `array_map`, not TRUE or FALSE.

So is it possible to use `array_map` and pass an argument to the callback function? Or perhaps make the `array_walk` return an array instead of boolean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432257/difference-between-array-map-array-walk-and-array-filter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need it to return an array.

Instead of:

```
$newArray = array_function_you_are_looking_for($oldArray, $funcName);
```

It's:

```
$newArray = $oldArray;
array_walk($newArray, $funcName);
```

Comment: But if I use `array_walk` the return value will be TRUE of FALSE. I want the return value to be an array like how `array_map` does.
So either find a way to pass an argument using `array_map` or find a way so that `array_walk` return array instead of boolean.

Comment: Does `array_walk` edit the original array on which it is called? Because if it does, this is pretty sweet.

Comment: that's because array_walk SETS the array. Try print_r($newArray); afterwards. Notice that Tomalak is NOT doing `$arr = array_walk($newArray, $funcName);` TRUE simply means 'it worked' and you can use the array that you inserted.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc
Yes, the array_walk modify the original array. That is why I need it to return an array instead of boolean.

Comment: @PENDO Doesn't that kind of depend on the function that's supplied? I messed around with `array_walk`, and it only modified the original array if the "walker" function that I defined used the `&` symbol: `function walker(&$val) { ... }`

Comment: the example above does what you want.... (1) first copy your original `$newArray = $originalArray;` .. (2) Alter the copier one `array_walk($newArray, 'function');` .. (3) use the new array `print_r($newArray);` .. perhaps we're missing some info, but this is what you need?

Comment: @Kemal: I'm just repeating my answer here but... you _don't need it to return an array_. It doesn't return an array, so you need something equivalent. That's what my code does. Study it in detail and you'll see that it solves your problem. Do you think `array_walk` would even exist, if it only returned `TRUE` or `FALSE` and had no other effect?

Comment: @Kemal: `array_walk` modifies the array passed to it, but in my example that is _NOT_ your original array. It's a copy. It's just the same as if the function returned a new, modified array for you.

Answer (score 6):

If you want return value is an array, just use array_map. To add additional parameters to array_map use "use", ex:

```
array_map(function($v) use ($tmp) { return $v * $tmp; }, $array);
```

or

```
array_map(function($v) use ($a, $b) { return $a * $b; }, $array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what kind of arguments you need to pass, you could create a wrapped function:

```
$arr = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
function mapper($val, $constant) {
    return $val * $constant;
}

$constant = 3;
function wrapper($val) {
    return mapper($val, $GLOBALS['constant']);
}

$arr = array_map('wrapper', $arr);
```

This actually seems too simple to be true. I suspect we'll need more context to really be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on Hieu's great answer, you can also use the $key => $value pairs of the original array. Here's an example with some code borrowed from comment section http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

The following will use '**use**' and include an additional parameter which is a new array.

Below code will grab "**b_value**" and "**d_value**" and put into a new array $new_arr
 (useless example to show a point)

```
// original array
$arr = ("a" => "b_value",
"c" => "d_value"); 

// new array
$new_arr = array();

array_map(function($k,$v) use (&$new_arr) { $new_arr[] = $v;}, array_keys($arr), $arr);
```

^ $k is key and $v is value

print_r of $new_arr is

```
Array
(
    [0] => b_value
    [1] => d_value
)
```