# Looking for array_map equivalent to work on keys in associative arrays

Tags: php, associative-array, array-map

Suppose I have an associative array:

```
    $array = array(
      "key1" => "value",
      "key2" => "value2");
```

And I wanted to make the keys all uppercase. How would I do than in a generalized way (meaning I could apply a user defined function to apply to the key names)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [array_change_key_case](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php) function of php

```
<?php
$input_array = array("FirSt" => 1, "SecOnd" => 4);
print_r(array_change_key_case($input_array, CASE_UPPER));
?>
```

Comment: Ah didn't know about that specific one, but the question was really more about a generalized mechanism like array_map where I could apply a user defined function to the keys.

Comment: Well with array_map you can't modulate keys as per your requirement. As more detailed explanation can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3432266/2266525

Answer (score 3):

Amazingly, there's an [`array_change_key_case` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above answers -- the following code **also** does the trick. The benefit is you can use this for any operation on the `keys` than **only** making the keys `uppercase`.

```
<?php
   $arr = array(
      "key1" => "value",
      "key2" => "value2"
   );

  echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);echo "</pre>";

  $arra = array_combine(
        array_map(function($k){ 
           return strtoupper($k); 
        }, array_keys($arr)
    ), $arr);

  echo "<pre>";print_r($arra);echo "</pre>";
```

This code outputs as:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value
    [key2] => value2
)
Array
(
    [KEY1] => value
    [KEY2] => value2
)
```

So this is just an *alternative* and *more generic* solution to change `keys` of an array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $newArray[strtoupper($k)] = $v;
}
```

Comment: This way, the old key still exists in the array. So, you also have to unset the old one using unset($array[$k]);