# Why is the array_walk() not working as intended?

Tags: php, arrays

The below `code does not work` as intended.

```
$fruits = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'cherry');

array_walk($fruits, function($a) {
        $a= ucfirst($a);
});

var_dump($fruits);
```

Why does this work when we pass the reference to an individual entry in the `$fruits` array.

```
array_walk(
    $fruits, 
    function(&$a) {
        $a = ucfirst($a);
    }
);
```

**Note**: I know `array_map` and `foreach` would work, but why does `array_walk()` not work?.

Comment: I don't think array_map or foreach would work, either. Unless you use references, you're not modifying the original element, you're modifying a copy.

Comment: If a reference *isn't* used then it is [Call By Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally PHP uses [Call by Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) semantics when evaluating a function. This means that reassignments to parameters will *not* affect variable bindings in the caller. Because of this the assignment in the "non working" code has no affect outside the callback and thus does not alter the walked array.

However, when a function parameter is specified as [`&..` (as discussed in Passing By Reference)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) the semantics switch to [Call by Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference). This means that variables in the caller *can* be altered through reassignment of the parameters. In this case the assignment to the local parameter *reassigns* the currently iterated array element through Call by Reference semantics and the code "works".

Now, [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/array_walk) "works" this way because it was *designed* to work with Call by Reference semantics. [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map), on the other hand, uses the return value of the callback.

Comment: Thanks! this should have more upvotes

Answer (score 3):

> If callback needs to be working with the actual values of the array,
>   specify the first parameter of callback as a reference.

According to the docs: http://php.net/array_walk

Comment: @HasinHayder "The below code does not work as intended". My comment is to the first part in which he is not passing by reference... Reading the docs clearly answers his question.

Answer (score 3):

With `function($a)` your passing a *copy* of `$a` to the function.

With `function(&$a)` your passing a *reference* to `$a` to the function. This way you can alter `$a` from within the function.

This is why `array_walk` is more memory efficient that `array_map`; you don't need an extra variable, you apply the function to each element on the original instead of returning the newly changed array.

Related question: [Difference between array_map, array_walk and array_filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432257/difference-between-array-map-array-walk-and-array-filter)

Answer (score 0):

In the first example `$a` is local variable. All changes out of the function are lost.
By the way, reference point to real array and changes it but not local copy.

Comment: It's a local variable in both examples. The difference is whether the variable contains a copy or reference.

Comment: `$a` is a local variable in both cases; however the semantics are changed.

Comment: Yeah, I meant _local copy_.