# Difference between array_filter() and array_map()?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I looked into the similar topics in web as well stack overflow, but could get this one into my head clearly. [Difference between array_map, array_walk and array_filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432257/difference-between-array-map-array-walk-and-array-filter)

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

$arr = array(2.4, 2.6, 3.5);

print_r(array_map(function($a) {
    $a > 2.5;
},$arr));

print_r(array_filter($arr, function($a){
    return $a > 2.5;
}));

?>
```

The above code returns me a filtered array whose **value is > 2.5**. Can i achieve what an `array_filter` does with an `array_map`?.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All three, [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), and [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), use a callback function to loop through an array much in the same way [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loops loop through an [$array](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) using [$key](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) => [$value](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) pairs.
For the duration of this post, I will be referring to the original array, passed to the above mentioned functions, as [$array](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), the index, of the current item in the loop, as [$key](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), and the value, of the current item in the loop, as [$value](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

**[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)** is likened to MySQL's SELECT query which SELECTs records but doesn't modify them.
array_filter's callback is passed the [$value](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) of the current loop item and whatever the callback returns is treated as a boolean.
If **true**, the item is included in the results.
If **false**, the item is excluded from the results.
Thus you might do:

```
<pre><?php
$users=array('user1'=>array('logged_in'=>'Y'),'user2'=>array('logged_in'=>'N'),'user3'=>array('logged_in'=>'Y'),'user4'=>array('logged_in'=>'Y'),'user5'=>array('logged_in'=>'N'));
function signedIn($value)
{
    if($value['logged_in']=='Y')return true;
    return false;
}
$signedInUsers=array_filter($users,'signedIn');
print_r($signedInUsers);//Array ( [user1] => Array ( [logged_in] => Y ) [user3] => Array ( [logged_in] => Y ) [user4] => Array ( [logged_in] => Y ) )
?></pre>
```

**[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)** on the other hand accepts multiple arrays as arguments.
If one array is specified, the $value of the current item in the loop is sent to the callback.
If two or more arrays are used, all the arrays need to first be passed through array_values as mentioned in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

> If the array argument contains string keys then the returned array
>   will contain string keys if and only if exactly one array is passed.
>   If more than one argument is passed then the returned array always has
>   integer keys

The first array is looped through and its value is passed to the callback as its first parameter, and if a second array is specified it will also be looped through and its value will be sent as the 2nd parameter to the callback and so-on and so-forth for each additional parameter.
If the length of the arrays don't match, the largest array is used, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

> Usually when using two or more arrays, they should be of equal length
>   because the callback function is applied in parallel to the
>   corresponding elements. If the arrays are of unequal length, shorter
>   ones will be extended with empty elements to match the length of the
>   longest.

Each time the callback is called, the return value is collected.
The keys are preserved only when working with one array, and array_map returns the resulting array.
If working with two or more arrays, the keys are lost and instead a new array populated with the callback results is returned.
array_map only sends the callback the $value of the current item not its $key.
If you need the key as well, you can pass `array_keys($array)` as an additional argument then the callback will receive both the $key and $value.
However, when using multiple arrays, the original keys will be lost in much the same manner as array_values discards the keys.
If you need the keys to be preserved, you can use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to grab the keys from the original array and [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to grab the values from the result of [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), or just use the result of [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) directly since it is already returning the values, then combine the two using [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

Thus you might do:

```
<pre><?php
$array=array('apple'=>'a','orange'=>'o');
function fn($key,$value)
{
    return $value.' is for '.$key;
}
$result=array_map('fn',array_keys($array),$array);
print_r($result);//Array ( [0] => a is for apple [1] => o is for orange )
print_r(array_combine(array_keys($array),$result));//Array ( [apple] => a is for apple [orange] => o is for orange )
?></pre>
```

**[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)** is very similar to `foreach($array as $key=>$value)` in that the callback is sent both a key and a value.  It also accepts an optional argument if you want to pass in a 3rd argument directly to the callback.
array_walk returns a boolean value indicating whether the loop completed successfully.
(I have yet to find a practical use for it)
Note that array_walk doesn't make use of the callback's return.
Since array_walk returns a boolean value, in order for array_walk to affect something,
you'll need to reference &$value so you have that which to modify or use a global array.
Alternatively, if you don't want to pollute the global scope, array_walk's optional 3rd argument can be used to pass in a reference to a variable with which to write to.

Thus you might do:

```
<pre><?php
$readArray=array(1=>'January',2=>'February',3=>'March',4=>'April',5=>'May',6=>'June',7=>'July',8=>'August',9=>'September',10=>'October',11=>'November',12=>'December');
$writeArray=array();
function fn($value,$key,&$writeArray)
{
  $writeArray[$key]=substr($value,0,3);
}
array_walk($readArray,'fn',&$writeArray);
print_r($writeArray);//Array ( [1] => Jan [2] => Feb [3] => Mar [4] => Apr [5] => May [6] => Jun [7] => Jul [8] => Aug [9] => Sep [10] => Oct [11] => Nov [12] => Dec )
?></pre>
```

Comment: really great explanations.  The array_filter analogy with the SQL query really made it clear for me thanks.  In my 10+ years with PHP I have pretty much rarely used any of the built in array functions so I am now taking the time to explore them all some so these examples are nice.  I really think a lot of PHP developers struggle to understand all the array functions and gives me the idea for a good detailed blog post to cover all the PHP array functions.  Would you be interested in contributing to such a blog article?

Comment: you should add `array_reduce`

Answer (score 6):

`array_filter` returns the elements of the original array for which the function returns true.

`array_map` returns an array of the results of calling the function on all the elements of the original array.

I can't think of a situation where you could use one instead of the other.

Answer (score 5):

`array_map` Returns an array containing all the elements of array after applying the callback function to each one.

for example:

```
$a=array("a","bb","ccd","fdjkfgf");
$b = array_map("strlen",$a);
print_r($b);

//output
Array
(
    [0] => 1    //like strlen(a)
    [1] => 2    //like strlen(bb)
    [2] => 3    //like strlen(ccd)
    [3] => 7    //like strlen(fdjkfgf)
)
```

whereas `array_filter` return only those elements of array for which the function is true

example: remove "bb" value from array

```
function test_filter($b)
  {
    if($b=="bb")
       {
          return false;
       }
     else
       {
          return true;
       }
  }
$a=array("a","bb","ccd","fdjkfgf");
$b = array_filter($a,"test_filter");
print_r($b);

//output
Array
(
    [0] => a     //test_filter() return true
    [2] => ccd    //test_filter() return true
    [3] => fdjkfgf //test_filter() return true
)
```

Answer (score 4):

`array_filter` works without a callable (function) being passed, whereas for `array_map` it is mandatory.

e.g.

```
$v = [true, false, true, true, false];
$x = array_filter($v);

var_dump($x);
array(3) { [0]=> bool(true) [2]=> bool(true) [3]=> bool(true) }
```

`array_walk` changes the actual array passed in, whereas `array_filter` and `array_map` return new arrays, this is because the array is passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

- array_map has no collateral effects while array_map never changes its arguments.
- The resulting array of array_map/array_walk has the same number of
  elements as the argument(s); array_filter picks only a subset of the
  elements of the array according to a filtering function. It does
  preserve the keys.

Example:

```
<pre>
<?php

$origarray1 = array(2.4, 2.6, 3.5);
$origarray2 = array(2.4, 2.6, 3.5);

print_r(array_map('floor', $origarray1)); // $origarray1 stays the same

// changes $origarray2
array_walk($origarray2, function (&$v, $k) { $v = floor($v); }); 
print_r($origarray2);

// this is a more proper use of array_walk
array_walk($origarray1, function ($v, $k) { echo "$k => $v", "\n"; });

// array_map accepts several arrays
print_r(
    array_map(function ($a, $b) { return $a * $b; }, $origarray1, $origarray2)
);

// select only elements that are > 2.5
print_r(
    array_filter($origarray1, function ($a) { return $a > 2.5; })
);

?>
</pre>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
0 => 2.4
1 => 2.6
2 => 3.5
Array
(
    [0] => 4.8
    [1] => 5.2
    [2] => 10.5
)
Array
(
    [1] => 2.6
    [2] => 3.5
)
```