# array_filter on PHP 7

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have a few lines of codes that will convert array values to uppercase. This work fine on my local development server using PHP 5.6, however it fails using PHP 7.0. What is causing it to fail?

```
function make_uppercase(&$word) {
    $word = strtoupper ( $word );
    return $word;
}

$fish = array (
        "hampala ampalong",
        "hampala macrolipedota" 
);
print_r ( array_filter ( $fish, "make_uppercase" ) );
```

Comment: Maybe you want `array_map` instead of `array_filter`?

Comment: You need to try with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008443/how-to-convert-array-values-to-lowercase-in-php

Comment: Oh. The result are different http://phpio.net/s/1bpu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write this. This will solve your problem

```
function make_uppercase(&$word) {
        $word = strtoupper ( $word );
        return $word;
    }

    $fish = array (
            "hampala ampalong",
            "hampala macrolipedota" 
    );
    print_r ( array_map ( "make_uppercase", $fish  ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

[Difference between array_filter() and array_map()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698954/difference-between-array-filter-and-array-map)
You should use `array_map` instead of `array_filter`.

But I am wondering why your code has different result between PHP 5 and PHP 7.
http://phpio.net/s/1bpu