# Why is array_map failing here?

Tags: php, array-map

I'm attempting to apply a function to an array of animals.  I want to embolden them.

```
$arr = array('cat', 'dog');

function makemebold($item)
{
    return "<b>$item</b>"; // or something more interesting... 
}
```

---

Let's check out the original array:

```
// dump original array
var_dump($arr); echo '<br>';
```

Returns:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "cat" [1]=> string(3) "dog" }
```

---

Now, let's apply array_map:

```
array_map($arr, 'makemebold');
var_dump($arr); echo '<br>';
```

Nothing doing:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "cat" [1]=> string(3) "dog" }
```

---

Now, array_walk:

```
array_walk($arr, 'makemebold');
var_dump($arr); echo '<br>';
```

Same as above - no change:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "cat" [1]=> string(3) "dog" }
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between array\_map, array\_walk and array\_filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432257/difference-between-array-map-array-walk-and-array-filter)

Answer (score 1):

`array_map` doesn't modify the input array, it returns a new array with results of calling the function on each element of the input.

```
$bold_arr = array_map('makemebold', $arr);
var_dump($bold_arr); echo '<br>';
```

Comment: I'm getting: 
`PHP Warning:  array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'cat' not found`

Comment: You had the arguments to `array_map` backwards, and I stupidly copied that.

Comment: Ugh, bitten by the inconsistent argument order again.  Thanks.