# How to get array_walk working with PHP built in functions?

Tags: php, arrays, ceil

I just want to use `array_walk()` with `ceil()` to round all the elements within an array. But it doesn't work.

The code:

```
$numbs = array(3, 5.5, -10.5); 
array_walk($numbs, "ceil"); 
print_r($numbs);
```

*output should be: 3,6,-10*

The error message:

*Warning:  ceil() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given on line 2*

*output is: 3,5.5,-10.5* (Same as before using ceil())

I also tried with `round()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with another PHP function.
You can create "your own ceil function".
In that case it is very easy to solve:

```
function myCeil(&$list){  
    $list =  ceil($list);  
}  

$numbs = [3, 5.5, -10.5];  
array_walk($numbs, "myCeil"); 

// $numbs output
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 6
    [2] => -10
)
```

Answer (score 10):

Use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead.

```
$numbs = array(3, 5.5, -10.5);
$numbs = array_map("ceil", $numbs);
print_r($numbs);
```

[`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) actually passes 2 parameters to the callback, and some built-in functions don't like being called with too many parameters (there's a note about this on the docs page for `array_walk`).  This is just a *Warning* though, it's not an error.

`array_walk` also requires that the first parameter of the callback be a *reference* if you want it to modify the array.  So, `ceil()` was still being called for each element, but since it didn't take the value as a reference, it didn't update the array.

`array_map` is better for this situation.

Comment: You're welcome  :-)  Sometimes one `array_*` function is better than another, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

That is because `array_walk` needs function which first parameter is a reference `&`

```
function myCeil(&$value){
    $value = ceil($value);
}

$numbs = array(3, 5.5, -10.5); 
array_walk($numbs, "myCeil"); 
print_r($numbs);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because `ceil($param)` expects only one parameter instead of two.

What you can do:

```
$numbs = array(3, 5.5, -10.5); 
array_walk($numbs, function($item) {
    echo ceil($item);
});
```

If you want to save these values then go ahead and use `array_map` which returns an array.

**UPDATE**

I suggest to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432257/difference-between-array-map-array-walk-and-array-filter#answer-3432266) on stackoverflow which explains very well the differences between `array_map`, `array_walk`, and `array_filter`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not quite.  The *warning* says "ceil() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given".  `array_walk` will call your callback function and pass it 2 parameters (`$value` and `$key`).  The array wasn't getting updated because `array_walk` will only do that if the `$value` parameter is a *reference* (and its value is updated in the callback).