# mysqli_real_escape_string with array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function, mysqli

My code is like this

```
 public function addQuestions($data){


    $ans = array();
    $ans[1] = $data['ans1'];
    $ans[2] = $data['ans2'];
    $ans[3] = $data['ans3'];
    $ans[4] = $data['ans4'];
    $ans= mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data[$ans]);

}
```

Is this right way to use array in this sql function ??

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string second parameter is `escape string` 
 `mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

Comment: It has to be mentioned. You shouldn't be escaping data for sql queries - you should use prepared and parameterized queries. That way you are actually executing safe and secure queries, and you don't mangle data. Win win

Comment: Since there are a lot of answers recommending to use functions like `array_walk` and `array_map`, I would recommend checking out this answer explaining the differences: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3432266/4796321

Comment: Your code and approach are outdated for at least a decade. We're all using parameterized queries and don't have to worry about escaping anything any more. I suggest you do a bit of googling to see what we're talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you wish to do something to each element of array $ans, it would be most appropriate to use [array_map()](http://www.php.net/array_map), as follows:

```
public function addQuestions($data){


    $ans = array();
    $ans[1] = $data['ans1'];
    $ans[2] = $data['ans2'];
    $ans[3] = $data['ans3'];
    $ans[4] = $data['ans4'];

    $escaped_ans = array_map(function( $e ) {
             return mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->db->link, $e);
    }, $ans );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on Milan's post, but beware of array_walk, it won't change your original array. For Milan's code to actually affect your array, the function would have to be

```
function myescape(&$val) //Note the '&' which calls $val by reference.
{
    $val = mysqli_real_escape_string($val);
}

array_walk($ans, 'myescape');
```

To answer your question though:

```
public function addQuestions($data){
    $ans = array('',$data['ans1'],$data['ans2'],$data['ans3'],$data['ans4']);
    //I would recommend using an object/associative array in this case though, just the way $data is already

    $ans_escaped = array_map(function($val) {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $val);
    }, $ans);

    //do whatever you need to do with escaped array
}
```

My advice though, would be to really look into prepared statements. It might just seem like extra work that you don't want to bother with - at first - but once you learn it, you will never want to do it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an array, and you want `mysqli_real_escape_string` on each element of an array, you can use `array_walk()`:

```
function myescape($val)
{
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($val);
}
```

... then

```
array_walk($ans, 'myescape');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use MYSQL PDO you won't need add "mysqli_real_escape_string" because all your variables a safe (from SQL injection) after you bind it

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Either way, the function is redundant if prepared and bound statements are employed